# Как записывать в БД имя пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite3

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['subscribe'])
def start(message):

    connect = sqlite3.connect('users5.db')

    cursor = connect.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login_id(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        user_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)""")

    connect.commit()

    people_id = message.chat.id
    user1_name = message.chat.first_name
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM login_id WHERE id = {people_id}")
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_name FROM login_id WHERE user_name = {user1_name} ")
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data is None:
        users_id = [message.chat.id, 'user_name']
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO login_id VALUES(?);", users_id)
        connect.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты подписался_ась на рассылку✅')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты уже подписан')
```

Как сделать чтобы кроме айди пользователя записывать имя пользователя, я вот вроде что то пытался сделать но не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты получается записываешь только юзер айди, для того чтобы записать еще и имя пользователя напиши отредактируй:

```
users_id = message.chat.id
first_name = message.chat.first_name
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO login_id VALUES(?, ?);", (users_id, f'{first_name}'))
```

Полный код:

```
import telebot
import sqlite3
from telebot.types import Message

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token="6930726784:AAEsOqe0QfHt3RGbbwpBzmc88vFKb8XNdL8")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['subscribe'])
def subscribe(message: Message):
connect = sqlite3.connect('users5.db')

cursor = connect.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login_id(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
user_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)""")

connect.commit()

people_id = message.chat.id
user1_name = message.chat.first_name
cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM login_id WHERE id = '{people_id}'")
cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_name FROM login_id WHERE user_name = '{user1_name}' ")
data = cursor.fetchone()
if data is None:
    users_id = message.chat.id
    first_name = message.chat.first_name
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO login_id VALUES(?, ?);", (users_id, f'{first_name}'))
    connect.commit()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты подписался_ась на рассылку✅')
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты уже подписан')  
    
bot.polling()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось!

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то писал оболочку для sqlite3, немного переделал для тебя, мб поможет?

```
from sqlite3 import connect, Cursor, Connection
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Iterable
from os.path import basename


class DataBase(ABC):
    def __init__(self, db_name: str) -> None:
        self.__db_name = db_name
        self._table_name = basename(db_name).replace('.db', '')
        self.__db: Connection = connect(db_name)
        self.__curs: Cursor = self.__db.cursor()
        self.__create_table()

    def get_all_data(self) -> list:
        self.__curs.execute(f'SELECT * FROM {self._table_name}')
        return self.__curs.fetchall()

    def get_rows(self, **params) -> list:
        params = ', '.join(f'{k}={repr(v)}' for k, v in params.items())
        self.__curs.execute(f'SELECT * FROM {self._table_name} WHERE {params}')
        return self.__curs.fetchall()

    def write_data(self, fields: list[str], values: Iterable) -> None:
        data, fields = ', '.join(map(repr, values)), ', '.join(fields)
        command = f'INSERT INTO {self._table_name} ({fields}) VALUES ({data})'
        self.__curs.execute(command)

    def del_rows(self, **params) -> None:
        params = ', '.join(f'{k}={repr(v)}' for k, v in params.items())
        self.__curs.execute(f'DELETE FROM {self._table_name} WHERE {params}')

    def run_command(self, command: str, *params) -> list:
        self.__curs.execute(command, *params)
        return self.__curs.fetchall()

    @abstractmethod
    def _get_table(self) -> str:
        pass

    def __create_table(self) -> None:
        self.__curs.execute(self._get_table())

    def __enter__(self) -> 'DataBase':
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb) -> None:
        if exc_type: del self

    def __del__(self) -> None:
        self.__db.commit()
        self.__db.close()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'[DataBase: {self.__class__.__name__}]'


class UsersDB(DataBase):
    def _get_table(self) -> str:
        return f'''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {self._table_name} (
                   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                   user_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)
                '''

    def get_row_by_id(self, id_row: int) -> tuple[int, str]:
        return self.get_rows(id=id_row)[-1]

    def write_data(self, user_name: str) -> None:
        fields = ('user_name', )
        values = (user_name, )
        super().write_data(fields, values)

    def del_row_by_id(self, id_row: int) -> None:
        self.del_rows(id=id_row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with UsersDB('test_users_db.db') as db:
        print('Writing data...')
        db.write_data('Errors')
        db.write_data('Alexa')
        db.write_data('Bob')
        print(db.get_all_data(), "- it's get_all_data(),")
        print(db.get_rows(user_name='Bob'), "- it's get_rows() (select by user_name='Bob'),")
        print(db.get_row_by_id(2), "- it's get_row_by_id(),")
        db.del_row_by_id(2); print('the "del_row_by_id" method is launched.')
        print(db.get_all_data())
        db.del_rows(user_name='Alexa'); print("the \"del_rows\" method is launched (deletes by user_name='Bob').")
        print(db)
```

Comment: `WHERE {params}` - код сжечь, автора расстрелять. Можно наоборот. / Не используйте конкатенацию для составления sql-запросов! Используйте параметры.